# Natural language processing library in java

Tags: java, nlp

For my small POC, I am looking for any open source library using which i can make use of natural language processing, preferably in java. Basically i am planning to have a application which takes input from user in human language and  return the results by filtering through supplied documents or web. Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "input from the user in human language" is in text format? If true, you are looking for a text data retriever. The [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) is really helpful once has vast documentation, examples, built in functionalities, pretty easy to use and great community collaboration.

A lot of challenges inherited from human natural language, like stemming and stopwords, has really good and easy to use API. For example:

```
TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(
                Version.LUCENE_36, new StringReader(input));
        tokenStream = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenStream, stopWordsSet);
        tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(tokenStream);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me to some example on github or somewhere else which uses natural language in text for querying the data.?

Comment: Yes simple query would be from user like "What are the registered TCP ports for Oracle webcenter ?" To answer this I need to go through webcenter's release documents or search through web.